# What is the best way to prevent the same trigger function from executing twice?

Tags: javascript, triggers, dom-events

A trigger can be applied at the form level and/or at the item level.  What is the best way for it *not* to be executed the second time?

```
<form id='f'>
  <input id='i' type='text' />
</form>

<script>
validate = function(e) { ... }
reformat = function(e) { ... }
document.getElementById('f').addListener('change',validate,true);
document.getElementById('i').addListener('change',validate,true);
document.getElementById('i').addListener('change',reformat,true);
</script>
```

Context: a data dictionary says item `i` needs to be validated immediately, and the app writer says all items in the form should be validated immediately.

It's the same function, usually called once, but sometimes twice.

What's the best way to keep the `validate` function from being executing twice?

Note: `e.stopPropagation()` stops *all* further calls on the `click` event, so that the `reformat` trigger is no longer called.

Comment: From the context you mention I'm not sure why you think that means you need to literally assign the event handler twice. Having said that, have you looked at `event.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: @nnnnnn - validate function on the item is called twice, first as a listener to the item and second as a listener to the form. imho  `stopPropagation` has no effect, since two different calls.

Comment: `stopPropagation()` has no effect "in your humble opinion", or "in your experience when you tried it out"? In any case I think you're much better off dropping the listener on the input. You don't need both. Even given your stated context about the double requirement: if my insurance company says I have to wear a seatbelt and the road rules say I have to wear a seatbelt does that mean I have to wear two seatbelts?

Comment: @nnnnn - from my improperly tested experience.  please see corrected example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a prop in the event param to make sure it runs once:

```
validate = function(e) { if (e.done) return; /* code */ e.done = true; }
document.getElementById('f').addListener('change',validate,true);
document.getElementById('i').addListener('change',validate,true);
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hG5Py/3/)

Although I don't see why you're binding the event twice

EDIT: For cross browserness (read: IE) change it to this:

```
validate = function(e) {
    if ((e = e || window.event).done) return;
    /* code */ 
    e.done = true;
}
document.getElementById('f').addListener('change',validate,true);
document.getElementById('i').addListener('change',validate,true);
```

## [Edited DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hG5Py/4/)

Comment: OUTSTANDING!  changed from `e.done` to `e.validate` since hanging more triggers on the event, but worked beautifully!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea (based on http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html):

```
function cancelBubbling(e) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;

    e.cancelBubble = true;

    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}

var validate = function(e) {
    cancelBubbling(e); // important!

    ...
};
```

Comment: you are right, but added more to question to clarify - `stopPropagation` will prevent the function `validate` from being called twice, but at the cost of preventing `reformat` from being called at all.

Comment: Good point! In that case I might wrap "change" and "reformat" inside a handler of its own and bind that to "i" instead. Problem solved.